# Will somebody from SO be at the Open Help 2012?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, meetups

Stack Overflow is being used as the primary support channel by some important projects.

Will someone be attending the [Open Help Conference](http://openhelpconference.com/) in 2012?

[update]

I'm not involved with the event organization (would try to drag Jeff for a talk, for sure).

Comment: Five days notice? Maybe you should have asked about this earlier.

Answer (score 4):

I was asked to submit a talk on Stack Exchanges (in an Ask Ubuntu context) but unfortunately due to my schedule I am unable to attend, however I'll make sure to hit it up next time and submit a talk.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for everyone, but far as I know, we had no plans to specifically *send* someone to that conference. Since it's in Ohio and [none of us are](https://stackexchange.com/about/team), it's unlikely that any employees will be attending unless some made personal plans to go.

You might run into some Stack Overflow users, though. There's gotta be at least some overlap with attendees. :)